# How to call a JS function in the view from the model in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm setting up a NET.ASP application using the MVC model, and I've come across an issue with activating a function already written in the Razor page, which needs to be activated post-page-load, after some computations.
In this case, my model is getting and parsing some data in the background, which the JavaScript needs to wait to be done.
The goal is to use that data to build a list showcasing it.

I'm rather certain that unless I have a way of triggering a script already written in the page from the model, I would have to write and activate on page-load a JavaScript function that would periodically check whether a boolean in the model is set to true and if so then to activate the data loading function in question.
The question is, when - is there a way to trigger the script from the model?

Unfortunately, every solution to this issue I've come across is for Web Forms, or uses controls in some way.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function showDataMined()
        {
            // Do things
        }

        function checkDataReady()
        {
            // Sleep for 3 seconds then if Model.dataReady call showDataMined()
            // Is this really the best practice?
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    // Stuff
</body>
</html>
```

I simply want to call showDataMined when the model is ready for it to be called.
Is there a way to do this without checking periodically for some boolean? Perhaps somehow with the Observer pattern?

Answer (score 0):

throw it in an IIFE ("iffy"). An IIFE is an Immediately Invoked Function Expression. It basically automatically calls itself.. hence the () at the end

```
(function(){ 
    function showDataMined()
    {
        // Do things
    }

    function checkDataReady()
    {
        // Sleep for 3 seconds then if Model.dataReady call showDataMined()
    }
})();
```

Comment: I want to avoid waiting for the data in this way.
Is there no way to invoke "showDataMined" from the model, without using "checkDataReady"?

Comment: I dont think you can invoke it from the model, models are basically data objects...  have you tried SignalR?

Comment: I have not tried it, but I don't want to overload a simple uni assignment with libraries we haven't touched on. How would you go about triggering a view function otherwise?

Comment: i would trigger the method in javascript with ajax... once data is returned from SQL or some random API to the View, then iterate/loop through the data and check to see if the condition of the boolean value is true, if true then do something

Comment: create your function so that every time data is received, it's going to get checked by that condition (like customs at an airport haha)

Comment: AJAX! Finally, someone points me in the right direction. Thank you!
I have to ask though - how would I make my function check a condition every time data is received to the model? Or is there some condition to check whether data is received to the AJAX files?

Comment: Once the C# model is mapped, it's still too early to check, but once it gets to the View, that's when the script should run. if you write your code accordingly, it should happen automatically.

so when the page loads, im assuming the javascript is going to receive some data... whichever function is receiving the data, do that computation, throw a condition to check whether the boolean property is true or false. so when every time data is received (yes everytime) it will automatically go through the lines of code that you've written and execute accordingly.